# How to build successfully lineageOS 20.0 in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: build, android-source, ubuntu-20.04, lineageos

````
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=13
LINEAGE_VERSION=20.0-20230817-UNOFFICIAL-star2lte
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_star2lte
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.2.0-26-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.3-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=TQ3A.230805.001
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=vendor/samsung/exynos9810-common device/samsung/exynos9810-common hardware/google/interfaces hardware/google/pixel hardware/samsung hardware/samsung/aidl/p
ower-libperfmgr vendor/samsung/star2lte```
============================================
````

[100% 398/398] analyzing Android.bp files and generating ninja file at out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_o
ut "out/soong"     --out "out"     -o out/soong/build.ninja --globListDir build --globFile out/soong/globs-build.ninja -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/s
oong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.build Android.bp
error: vendor/samsung/exynos9810-common/Android.bp:1867:1: module "libaptX_encoder" variant "android_arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a53_shared": module source path "vendor/samsung/exynos9810
-common/proprietary/product/lib64/libaptX_encoder.so" does not exist
11:07:51 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

##### failed to build some targets (42 seconds)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have not clearly mentioned what problem you have, but based on what I can see is that in your vendor path :

```
module source path: "vendor/samsung/exynos9810 -common/proprietary/product/lib64/libaptX_encoder.so" does not exist
```

that means you have a file called **

> libaptX_encoder.so

** missing in your directory. Check the latest vendor tree for exynos9810 and kindly update to solve the error.